# Research connecting reflection/introspection in computing and metacognition

Tags: metacognition

I would like to know if the notion of reflection/introspection in computing has prompted research in other fields other than computer science, e.g cognitive sciences.

In particular, I would love to read any work that makes the connection between reflection/introspection and metacognition.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) has a concise introduction on the two notions:

> In computing, type introspection is the ability of a program to examine the type or properties of an object at runtime. Some programming languages possess this capability.
>
> Introspection should not be confused with reflection, which goes a step further and is the ability for a program to manipulate the values, meta-data, properties and/or functions of an object at runtime. Some programming languages, e.g. Java, also possess that capability.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a philosophical question that is related to the same cognitive science terms only by using the same words for very different things.